# Having trouble with PHP updating a database

Tags: php, mysql

I've connected to a database by using

```
function db_connect() {
   $result = new mysqli('localhost','root', '******', 'DB');
   if (!$result) {
     throw new Exception('Could not connect to database server');
   } else {
     return $result;
   }
}
```

But when I go to register a new customer, I get 'Could not register to DB' and that piece of code is

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "insert into user values('".$username."', sha1('".$password."'), '".$email."')");
  if (!$result) {
    throw new Exception('Could not register to DB.');
  }
```

And I have a user table in my DB. The values in the table `user` are:

```
username varchar(100),
email varchar(150),
passwd varchar(17)
```

Comment: You probably making a mistake in your values. Double check if your SQL is correct. You can show us your user table columns.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte I've edited the question :)

Comment: In your second snippet, it looks like you have `$conn = db_connect();` before this snippet. Is that correct?

Comment: Try `insert into user (username, passwd, email) values ...`

Comment: don't output fixed error messages. they're basically useless. `throw new Exception(mysqli_error($conn))` will TELL you what failed.

Comment: You never ever set `$conn`

Comment: @ChrisForrence the first snippet which is the `$result = new mysqli` is first

Comment: Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). Make sure that you [don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says [your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: @JayBlanchard I've declared `$conn`

Comment: Where have you declared it?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I've declared it above `$result = mysqli_query($conn`

Comment: You may have declared `$conn` but did you load it by doing `$conn = db_connect()` somewhere

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have used `$conn = db_connect()`

Comment: **It would have been useful to have shown that in your code snippet**

Comment: @RiggsFolly Sorry!

Answer (score 4):

When you have an INSERT statement without columns, the order of columns will be expected to match the table schema.

Based on that, let's re-examine your snippet:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "insert into user values('".$username."', sha1('".$password."'), '".$email."')");
if (!$result) {
    throw new Exception('Could not register to DB.');
}
```

According to this, you're inserting a username, then a password, then an email. However, your table schema defines a username first, then an email, then the password.

Based on that, let's use the below snippet instead. Note that this utilizes prepared statements, which prevents SQL injection attacks.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO user (username, passwd, email) VALUES (?,?,?)";

if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query)) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $username, sha1($password), $email);

    /* execute query */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    /* close statement */
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
```

An additional problem: your password field in the database is much too short (17 characters). An SHA-128-hashed password is exactly 40 characters, and to use the password_* methods, you'd need at least 60 characters. I'd advise simply setting the password field to 255 characters.

Please also keep [Jay Blanchard's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684772/having-trouble-with-php-updating-a-database#comment62846952_37684772) in mind to use the password_* family of functions. instead of hashing a password with SHA1.

Comment: Nice use of a prepared statement!

Answer (score 2):

If you've properly connected you have a syntax error in your query with the password. Here is your current code:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "insert into user values('".$username."', sha1('".$password."'), '".$email."')");
```

If you insist on leaving yourself open for potential SQL injection attacks you would change the concatenation to be like this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "insert into user values('".$username."','". sha1($password)."', '".$email."')");
```

This will allow PHP's `sha1()` function to execute properly. If you wished to use MySQL's built-in `sha1()` function then the concatenation here would not be used as I have done.

---

As stated before [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says [your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

In addition you may want to consider using PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). Make sure that you [don't escape passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: On one hand, there does appear to be an SHA1 function available within MySQL ([reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_sha1)). That being said, using the method in this fashion would expose the plain-text password in any database logs, which is certainly dangerous!

Comment: True, and I'll clarify.

Answer (score 2):

This line is definitely one of your problems

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, 
           "insert into user values('".$username."', sha1('".$password."'), '".$email."')");
```

change it to

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, 
          "insert into user values('$username', '$email',  '" . sha1($password) "')");
```

NOTE Change the order to match your schema as well as de-cluttered the string concatenation.

NOTE2: Your password field is too short to hold a complete hashed password. For future proofing I suggest a full `varchar(255)`

It would be better to use `password_hash()` though like this

```
$hashed = password_hash($password);

$result = mysqli_query($conn, 
          "insert into user values('$username', '$hashed', '$email')");
```

And then to check when user logs in again use

```
if ( password_verify($_POST['password'], $db_hashed_password) ) {
    echo 'Password OK';
} else {
    echo 'Password failed';
}
```